# How would the RealEstateAgent Schema.org type be used as a LocalBusiness?

Tags: schema.org, local-seo

The ***Agent*** part of [this type](https://schema.org/RealEstateAgent) is throwing me off. A real estate *agent* is part of an agency so when this type is being used to identify a local business, is the agency the [`address`](https://schema.org/address)? Or would a real estate agent not use this schema to identify a local business if the agent is part of an agency? Can you be an agent without an agency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Schema.org type [`RealEstateAgent`](https://schema.org/RealEstateAgent) is a sub-type of [`LocalBusiness`](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness), which represents a "particular physical business".

So `RealEstateAgent` represents the business (with a physical location, i.e., an `address`), not a person that works for this business (that would have to be an entity of type [`Person`](https://schema.org/Person)). Of course a single person can form a `RealEstateAgent` business, but the person and the business would still be different entities.

Comment: I've got one more question. *Let me know if I should ask this as a new question*. Can this markup be used for a real estate agent if the `employee` type is used to identify the agent? If so, would the `contactPoint` be the agent or the agency that the agent is part of?

Comment: @JohnRPerry: [`employee`](http://schema.org/employee) is a property which allows to say that a `RealEstateAgent` employs a `Person`. The `RealEstateAgent` is still the item that represents the business, and `Person` is the item that represents the employee of that business. Each of these items can have a [`ContactPoint`](http://schema.org/ContactPoint); if it’s a contact point for the business, you’d specify it on `RealEstateAgent`, if it’s a contact point for the person, you’d specify it on `Person`.